# Attaching subscription_data metadata on Stripe payment links

Tags: stripe-payments

I need to attach metadata to the underlying Subscription that's generated from a Stripe payment link (not just the Payment, and not just the Payment Link session — but to the actual generated Subscription).

My request looks like this:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_links \
  -u sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX: \
  -d "line_items[0][price]"=price_XXXXXXXXXXXX \
  -d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1 \
  -d "subscription_data.metadata[account_id]"="test123"
```

That gives me the error "Received unknown parameter: subscription_data.metadata."

Any idea how to reformat this request? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've answered my own question—which is that, unfortunately, the payment_links endpoint doesn't accept "metadata" as a parameter for "subscription_data" so there is no way to pass Subscription metadata through a payment link.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to set the `metadata` on the Subscription object from the Payment Link.

If you need to set `metadata` on the Subscription object that gets generated by the Payment Link, then you'll want to set up a [webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) that listens for `customer.subscription.created` and makes an API call to update the Subscription with your `metadata`.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, `subscription_data` isn't supported on Payment Links (only Checkout Sessions).

I did find a trick that will allow you to do it, though:

1. Create a Checkout Session in `subscription` mode with your `subscription_data` and `recovery` enabled:

   curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions \
   -u sk_test_xxx \
   --data-urlencode success_url="https://example.com/success" \
   -d "line_items[0][price]"=price_xxx \
   -d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1 \
   -d "subscription_data[metadata][key]"=value \
   -d mode=subscription \
   -d "after_expiration[recovery][enabled]"=true
2. Expire this Checkout Session:

   curl -X POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/cs_test_xxx/expire \
   -u sk_test_xxx

In the response, you'll get a Checkout Session object (you can also see it in the `checkout.session.expired` event on your account), which contains a `after_expiration.recovery.url` that looks just like a Payment Links url (buy.stripe.com).

This link works just like a Payment Link, it doesn't expire, and can be reused. Except unlike a Payment Link, it benefits from the `subscription_data.metadata` setting that you set on your Session.

Now, this method is as unofficial as it gets. It's also worth mentioning that you can expire Sessions, and disable Payment Links, but you can't do any of that for this recovery link...